# Lock a button until a checkbox is checked

Tags: html, button, checkbox

Hi i'm trying to figure out how to disable a link until a checkbox is checked This is the link

```
< a class="link1" data-type="submit" >send< /a>
```

and the code for the checkbox is

```
< input type="checkbox" />
```

I need to force the visitor to check the checkbox before the link is active, this is for a contact form, this is to force them to agree to the terms and conditions before being able to send us a message.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you've tried thus far

Comment: Hello I currently only have a contact form linked to a send button, I do not have any code for the checkbox as i'm unsure how to link a checkbox to another button. Sorry for the lack of info.

Comment: Hi i've updated the information in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit-btn" id="submitbtn" value="    Submit    " disabled="disabled" />
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onchange="document.getElementById('submitbtn').disabled = !this.checked;"/>
```

Comment: Hi Nick, this doesn't work for me, it is still submitting without the checkbox ticked

Comment: My submit button looks like this <a class="link1" data-type="submit" >send</a> and is not an input, will it still work?

Comment: i wasn't aware that you are displaying button using anchor tag.
disable is not valid with anchor tags

rather use 

$('a').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
});

Comment: I tried replacing the anchor tag button with the code you suggested, it still submitted regardless of whether the box was ticked.

Comment: I fixed the problem, I added disabled="disabled" into your code for the submit button and it works. Thanks Nick!

Comment: sorry, i missed it while adding the html and did not crosschecked my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

For example. On document load you disable button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#buttonId').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

or

Set disable in HTML:

```
<input id="buttonId" type="button" disabled="disabled" value="button caption" />
```

Next on checkbox checked - make button enabled:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
  $('#buttonId').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Hi, my submit button is like this <a class="link1" data-type="submit" >send</a>

Comment: I'm sorry for asking for more help but I do not know how to integrate the code you've shown above into this.

Comment: Change selector from $('buttonId') to $('.button_class')